# How to get notify when a user closes the browser in SignalR Blazor?

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I want to send a notification to all the users connected in a group when a user lefts. How can I do that?

As you can see in my code I've overridden the `OnDisconnectedAsync` method, but it works only when I call `HubConnection.DisposeAsync();`. But if I close the browser or tab, it does nothing.

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("User Joined.");
    return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User Left.");
    return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

Is there any way to get notified when the browser is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CircuitHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

> Blazor Server allows code to define a circuit handler , which allows running code on changes to the state of a user's circuit. A circuit handler is implemented by deriving from CircuitHandler and registering the class in the app's service container.

```
public class TrackingCircuitHandler : CircuitHandler 
{
    private HashSet<Circuit> circuits = new HashSet<Circuit>();
    public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        circuits.Add(circuit);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        circuits.Remove(circuit);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public int ConnectedCircuits => circuits.Count;
}
```

Circuit handlers are registered using DI

```
services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler, TrackingCircuitHandler>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a service class that derives from CircuitHandler:

### CircuitHandlerService.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CircuitHandlerService : CircuitHandler 
    {
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit> Circuits { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler CircuitsChanged;

        protected virtual void OnCircuitsChanged()
        => CircuitsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        public CircuitHandlerService()
        {
            Circuits = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit>();
        }

        public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Circuits[circuit.Id] = circuit;
            OnCircuitsChanged();
            return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Circuit circuitRemoved;
            Circuits.TryRemove(circuit.Id, out circuitRemoved);
            OnCircuitsChanged();
            return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.OnConnectionDownAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.OnConnectionUpAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }
               
    }
```

Add the service to the DI container:

```
services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler>(new CircuitHandlerService());
```

Test the service:

```
@page "/"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits

@inject CircuitHandler circuitHandler
@implements IDisposable


<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<p>
    Number of Circuits: @((circuitHandler as BlazorCircuitHandler.Services.CircuitHandlerService).Circuits.Count)
    <ul>
        @foreach (var circuit in (circuitHandler as BlazorCircuitHandler.Services.CircuitHandlerService).Circuits)
        {
            <li>@circuit.Key</li>
        }
    </ul>
</p>

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // register event handler
        (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerService).CircuitsChanged += HandleCircuitsChanged;
        
        
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // unregister the event handler when the component is destroyed
        (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerService).CircuitsChanged -= HandleCircuitsChanged;
        
       
    }

    public void HandleCircuitsChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // notify the UI that the state has changed
       InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}
```